# Is there a better way to Regex match a string of digits between the range of 2-100 than this?

Tags: ruby, regex

This is my attempt, is there a better way?

```
^([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)$
```

Comment: The pattern seems fine, why do you need to change it?

Comment: I wondered if there might be a more concise Regex matching method that I didn't know about, as the above seemed a little strange containing the three matching 'phrases'.

Comment: This is the best it get's. If possible, one shouldn't use regex to check numeric ranges, but extract the value and to the range check programatically.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness `^` and `$` are beginning of *line* and end of *line* in Ruby, they don't anchor to the beginning/ending of the *string*, you almost always want to use `\A` and `\z` in Ruby.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks! That's good to know. Is there not a multiline setting?

Comment: Why do you need a regex for this? Regexes are sometimes the right solution but not always.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness No, the `/m` and `/s` modifiers are AFAIK Perl-isms.

Comment: Neat, thanks, good to learn something new.

Comment: How is "better" defined here? More performant? Readability? More clearly shows the intent? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

The better way could be not to use regex.

```
puts 'in range' if (2..100) === '20'.to_i
```

Comment: What if string can be anything, not just a number? For example, `'20    '` will pass your test, but won't author's

Comment: @Nondv If that matters, a test should be added. Like the one in your answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately it needs to be a Ragex as I\m going to use within a JSON Schema string pattern matcher.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your context is and if you are concerned about performance.

I would do conversion to int:

```
str =~ /^(\d+)$/ && $1.to_i.between?(2, 100)
```

I think it is much easier to read than your regex. Basically, it says: "str is just a number and this number is between 2 and 100".

And this test is fully compatible with yours (equivalent)

Comment: Careful, `^` and `$` are *line* based in Ruby, not *string* based.

Comment: @muistooshort I know that, but author used them so I play along. It's out of initial question

Comment: But "is there a better way" would include using a correct regex, no?

Comment: We don't know what the problem is. I am pretty sure author is just concern about readability, not functionality so I presume $ works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You regex is not correct for Ruby. In Ruby, `^` matches at the beginning of a *line*, not the beginning of the *string*; similarly for `$` at the end of *line* not *string*.

In Ruby, `^` and `$` are almost always a mistake, you generally want to use `\A` and `\z` (respectively) instead:

```
\A([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)\z
```

If you want or need to use a regex, start with a regex that matches what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If that regex is just a piece of a bigger regexp or the regexp is kind of a parameter for passing to a function that just accepts a regexp then I don't think It can be better than that.

However, if you just use this for validating some numbers, then a much better approach is to cast the text to an integer a then validate with `>= 2 and <=100` or `between?`